# popup a javascript dialog box with a php var

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, while-loop

How is it possible to pop up the right javascript box when I'm using a While in PHP.
This is the code:

```
while($result= mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    <tr class="<?php echo $style;?>">
        <td><?php echo $result['commissie'];?></td>
        <td class="small"><?php echo $result['volgorde'];?></td>
        <td class="small">
            <div id="dialog-overlay"></div>
                <div id="dialog-box">
                    <div class="dialog-content">
                        <h1>Verwijder van commissie: "<?php echo $result['commissie'];?>"</h1>                                              
                        <div id="dialog-message">
                            <p>Weet je zeker dat je <?php echo $result['commissie'];?>. <?php echo $result_achternaam;?> wilt verwijderen uit de commissie? Dit betekend dat het contactpersoon automatisch zal worden verwijdert uit het systeem.</p>
                        </div>
                        <a href="../checks/delete_commissie.php?id=<?php echo $result['id'];?>" class="button">Ja</a>
                        <a href="#" class="button_no">Nee</a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div> 
             <a href="javascript:popup('<?php echo $result['id'];?>')"><img src="../../images/delete.png"/></a>
         </td>
    </tr>
<?php }//CLOSE THE WHILE
```

This is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('a.button_no').click(function () {     
    $('#dialog-overlay, #dialog-box').hide();       
    return false;
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
    if (!$('#dialog-box').is(':hidden')) popup();       
    }); 
});

function popup() {

    var maskHeight = $(document).height();  
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    var dialogTop =  (maskHeight/3) - ($('#dialog-box').height());  
    var dialogLeft = (maskWidth/2) - ($('#dialog-box').width()/2); 

    $('#dialog-overlay').css({height:maskHeight, width:maskWidth}).show();
    $('#dialog-box').css({top:dialogTop, left:dialogLeft}).show();           
}
```

The problem is when i show a dialog box the system wil always pop up the first one because in the table in the WHILE

Comment: 1. ids must be unique on a document ... 2. your passing a variable to `popup` and not receiving / doing anything with it ... 3. I suggest you use ajax to get the data/html for the popup, [see here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694693/how-to-have-jqueryui-dialog-box-dynamically-load-content)

Comment: You're missing a `?>` on the while() line.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue appears to be due to duplicate selectors generated in your while loop.  ID attributes need to be unique.

```
<div id="dialog-overlay"></div>
<div id="dialog-box">
```

The jQuery `$('#dialog-box')` will always select the first instance of #dialog-box.

You could increment a variable in your while loop and, then use that to trigger your box.

```
$i = 1;

while($result= mysql_fetch_array($data)){ ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $style;?>">
        <td><?php echo $result['commissie'];?></td>
        <td class="small"><?php echo $result['volgorde'];?></td>
        <td class="small">
            <div id="dialog-overlay<?php echo $i; ?>"></div>
                <div id="dialog-box<?php echo $i; ?>">
                    <div class="dialog-content">
                        <h1>Verwijder van commissie: "<?php echo $result['commissie'];?>"</h1>                                              
                        <div id="dialog-message<?php echo $i; ?>">
                            <p>Weet je zeker dat je <?php echo $result['commissie'];?>. <?php echo $result_achternaam;?> wilt verwijderen uit de commissie? Dit betekend dat het contactpersoon automatisch zal worden verwijdert uit het systeem.</p>
                        </div>
                        <a href="../checks/delete_commissie.php?id=<?php echo $result['id'];?>" class="button">Ja</a>
                        <a href="#" class="button_no" data-buttonID="<?php echo $i; ?>">Nee</a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div> 
             <a href="javascript:popup('<?php echo $result['id'];?>')"><img src="../../images/delete.png"/></a>
         </td>
    </tr>
<?php $i++; }//Increment $i andCLOSE THE WHILE
```

Javascript

```
var dialogBox = 1;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('a.button_no').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dialogBox = $(this).data('buttonID');   
        $('#dialog-overlay' + dialogBox + ', #dialog-box' + dialogBox).hide();       
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
       if (!$('#dialog-box' + dialogBox).is(':hidden')) popup();       
    }); 
});

function popup() {

    var maskHeight = $(document).height();  
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    var dialogTop =  (maskHeight/3) - ($('#dialog-box' + dialogBox).height());  
    var dialogLeft = (maskWidth/2) - ($('#dialog-box' + dialogBox).width()/2); 

    $('#dialog-overlay' + dialogBox).css({height:maskHeight, width:maskWidth}).show();
    $('#dialog-box' + dialogBox).css({top:dialogTop, left:dialogLeft}).show();           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at what your code does it seems like you could achieve it more easily by calling the function using an event handler, with the contextual `this` keyword. Obviously you need to use classes instead of ID's, as @PassKit mentioned

```
$("a").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
dialog = $(this).prev(); // will get the .dialog_overlay div
// now you can manipulate the dialog using `dialog` as a reference point. 
//e.g dialog.find(".dialog_box").show() etc...
});
```