# How to add jquery array into html form to add checkboxes dynamically into dialogue box

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

i have a jquery array which contains html code for generating checkboxes dyanmically.here is the contents of my jquery array and the name of my array is **output**

```
<input type="checkbox"   id="Mumbai" name="Mumbai" value="Mumbai" />Mumbai<br />,
<input type="checkbox"   id=" Delhi" name=" Delhi" value=" Delhi" /> Delhi<br />,
<input type="checkbox"   id=" Bangalore" name=" Bangalore" value=" Bangalore" />Bangalore<br />
```

Now as per my need i want to add this array called **output** into jquery dialogue box contained in html form ..

Here is my code..

```
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('<form id="myform" action="">output</form>')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Select Sites',
            buttons: {
                "Submit": function() {  $('form#myform').submit();},
                "Cancel": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
            }
        });
```

I have to add the array called **output** in the .html form which i have added like this shown in code but its not showing checkoxes instead it is showing output in the alert box message ..

Any help will be highly appreciated..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You will have to separate the html into two different parts. For example,

```
.html('<form id="myform" action="">' + output + '</form>')
```

Comment: thank you sir for your response but it is not showing checkbox in the dialogue box

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
    .html('<form id="myform" action="">'+$('input:checkbox').clone()+'</form>')
    .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(window).load(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'Sites',
            success: function(data) {
                var city=data.city
                for(var i in city)
                {
                   var output='<input type="checkbox"   id="'+city[i]+'" name="'+city[i]+'" value="'+city[i]+'" />'+city[i]+'<br />'
                }
                consoloe.log(output)
            }
        });
    });
```

Refer this [How to have jQueryUI dialog box dynamically load content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694693/how-to-have-jqueryui-dialog-box-dynamically-load-content)